# Python coding with numpy sympy

Tags: python, programming

New to python, and I am working on a problem with the ultimate goal of being able to evaluate

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}\bigg[\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\sqrt{x}+2^k)- \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-\sqrt{x}+2^k)\bigg]}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\sqrt{x}+2^k)+ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-\sqrt{x}+2^k)}$$

at whichever value of $x, n$ I choose.

First, I probably need to expand the function: how should I go about doing so? Perhaps sympy?
Then, how would I evaluate the sympy function?

Comment: sympy.expand() may do what you want, or it may make a mess. worth trying if you want to gain insight. also sympy.subs() is your friend. or just code it as a python function and evaluate in numpy

Comment: Also, observe that you have these products are very similar. Create a function $$f(\mathbb{\alpha})=\prod_k \alpha+2^k.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Do you have a reason you want to expand first before evaluating? Python is capable of computing the products without needing to expand first, so if there is not a compelling reason to do it, I would not bother.

Comment: @Alex S Oh, I did not know that! How would I do so?

Comment: You use sympy when you want to obtain algebraic expressions. If you just want to compute the above for specific $x,\,n$ (*not* the dummy variable $k$), just write a "normal" function in the way you would in any language, as per the existing answers. You don't even need numpy; unless you want to simultaneously compute on multiple inputs using numpy arrays, Python's standard math library is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

As the infinite product $\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1 + 2^{-k} a)$ converges for all $a$, it seems better numerically to compute the expression as
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}\bigg[\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1 + 2^{-k}\sqrt{x})- \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1 - 2^{-k}\sqrt{x})\bigg]}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1 + 2^{-k}\sqrt{x})+ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1 - 2^{-k}\sqrt{x})}$$
The following code does that

```
import numpy as np

def prod(a, n):
    res = 1.0
    y = a
    for k in range(n):
        res *= (1.0 + y)
        y /= 2.0
    return res

def expr(x, n):
    r = np.sqrt(x)
    u, v = prod(r, n), prod(-r, n)
    return r * (u - v)/(u + v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(10):
        print(expr(x, 30))

""" output ->
0.0
1.0
1.433872292244485
1.7430889640419365
2.0
2.2274334143759584
2.4351764585875912
2.6283079353312218
2.809840294960271
2.9817458083387267
"""
```

Comment: +1 This is better than my answer, the products as written by OP blow up quickly and will lead to overflow, even for moderate $n$.

Answer (score 3):

With `sympy` it's even easier (and more precise):

```
from sympy.abc import x, k, n
from sympy import Product, sqrt, simplify
nm = sqrt(x) * (Product(sqrt(x) + 2**k, (k, 0, n-1)) - Product(-sqrt(x) + 2**k, (k, 0, n-1)))
dn = (Product(sqrt(x) + 2**k, (k, 0, n-1)) + Product(-sqrt(x) + 2**k, (k, 0, n-1)))
r = nm / dn
# assign values, e.g., x=2, n=30 and simplify the expression r
r = r.subs({x:2, n:30})
simplify(r.doit(), full=True)
```

The above code will produce the output as the following rational number:

$\displaystyle \frac{15027793389823468799645258066452193394332497033326437886769757423624751185248020668383259645787227100364629147062572788303205899}{10480566136263082489017135219769116375568335802982506381129986143601518100707743247130303530922557209156825461255161211247319516}$

We may want to approximate the output rational number obtained with a float, using the following code:

```
Float(simplify(r.doit(), full=True), 20) # with precision of 20 digits
# 1.4338722922444847313
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
def prod(n,a):
    p=1
    for k in range(n):
       p*=a+2**k
    return p
def f(n,x):
    return np.sqrt(x)*(prod(np.sqrt(x))+prod(-np.sqrt(x)))/(prod(np.sqrt(x))-prod(-np.sqrt(x)))
```

The first function `prod` computes $\Pi_{k=0}^{n-1}(a+2^k)$ for given $n$ and $a$. The function `f` is the one you specified, which uses `prod` 4 times, each time with $\pm\sqrt{x}$ as $a$ in the argument.

Comment: I noticed in the return statement of f(n,x), when you were using the prod function you had defined, you only had one parameter. Why is this the case?